# Why 'ng' attribute not working in HTML tags?

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller

I am writing a simple and test application in ASP.NET MVC5 and also using Angular JS.
I added Angular scripts and somehow 'ng' attributes in HTML tags aren't working.
For example, in the code below i want to call a function 'Add()' in 'ng-click' event. This doesn't seem to be working because clicking 'Add' button should have called the 'Add()' function and cleared-off the UI fields entered by the user.

```
        $scope.Add = function() {
            $http({ method: "POST", data: $scope.Customer, url: "Submit" }).
                success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        $scope.Customer =
                        {
                            "CustomerCode": "",
                            "CustomerName": "",
                            "CustomerAmount": "",
                            "CustomerAmountColor": ""
                        };

                    }
            );
        }
<input id="Btn" type="button" value="Add customer" ng-click="Add()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

did you add the js controller which has the function, in your HTML?

Comment: Yes it had been added